# Update state when data changed in React+Redux

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc, react-redux

I'm too new to react. I'm curious about a few things. The first topic I was wondering, why the HTML tags in js?

I need to do a project. I have a method that returns json with .NET
I have a code like below.  How do I update the div when I add something into it?

This .net code.

```
private static readonly IList<Mock.Model.Skills> _Skills;


[Route("api/Skills/add")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Skills(Mock.Model.Skills Model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
    _Skills.Add(Model);
     return Json("true");
   }
   return Json(false);
}
```

And, js (react) code.

```
var Rows = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <span className="label label-info tags">{this.props.item.tag}</span>
        );
    }
});

var SkillsRow = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            items: []
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {

        $.get(this.props.dataUrl, function (data) {
            if (this.isMounted()) {
                this.setState({
                    items: data
                });
            }
        }.bind(this));
    },
    render: function () {
        var rows = [];
        this.state.items.forEach(function (item, index) {
            rows.push(<Rows class="label label-info tags" key={index} item={item} />);
        });
        return (<span>{rows}</span>);
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <SkillsRow dataUrl="/api/Skills" />,
    document.getElementById('skills-data')
);
```

This works well, but do not add. 
I wonder if this is the correct method?

Thank you to everyone who showed interest.

Comment: While I think any answer will be mainly opinion-based, the pattern you are using is fine for React. It isn't Redux though as you aren't using [a store](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add items to api, you can call something like this:

```
var SkillsRow = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      items: [],
      currentEditor: ''
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.updateSkillList()
  },
  updateSkillList: function() {
    $.get(this.props.dataUrl, function(data) {
      this.setState({
        items: data
      })
    }).bind(this)
  },
  handleEditorChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({
      currentEditor: event.target.value
    })
  },
  handlePostForm: function() {
    $.post('api/Skills/add', {skill: this.state.currentEditor}, function(data) {
      this.updateSkillList()
    })
  },
  renderSkillList: function() {
    this.state.items.map(function(item, idx) {
      return <Row className="label label-info tags" key={idx} item={item} />
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>
          <input value={this.state.currentEditor} onChange={this.handleEditorChange} />
          <button onClick={this.handlePostForm} />
        </span>
        <span>{this.renderSkillList()}</span>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
})
```

---

Edited:
Now i understood the question, you code will look something like this, also you will have to fix backend code to only receive the skill name, and then create the object (you can't create a C# object in javascript)

Comment: I'm getting error while debugging. Line => updateSkillList Unexpected token (15:20)

Comment: looks like you aren't using ES6, edited the code above

Comment: thanks, but it is not true that go to the server at certain intervals. I need access to the HTML to update function. Like 

<button onclick="saveAndUpdate()">Add New</button>

Comment: The code above was edited, look the changes and also look the observation in the footer.